# How do i make my character stretch?

Tags: rigging, armature, transforms

I love the way metarig's, rig has this elasticity and I want to know how I can do this for my custom rigs to create that "squash and stretch" effect, how do I make it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In every IK chain you can set the amount of stretch allowed for every bone of the chain, but - as the IK solver is calculated at the end, after all constraints stack - generally you have to use it as a basement for a real squash and stretch chain.

[image]

This is the "basic idea" of a stretchy chain:

[image]

A, B and C are control bones, while Def_01 and Def_02 are deforming bones.

Def_01 copies location of A and has a stretch to bone constraint pointing at B.

Def_02 copies location of B and has a stretch to bone constraint pointing at C.

In the final rig A,B and C will copy the location of the head of bones D, E and IK Target.

Take a look at the "Maintain Volume" constraint also, in order to achieve squashy and stretchy effects.

Comment: How do I make A, B and C copy the head locations of D, E and IK target? Also, my character's arm has a double-jointed elbow so basically, it's more like A, B, C and D to me instead.

Comment: Parenting or using copy loc constraint, depending on the rig architecture.